# Why is my multi-class segmentation using tensorflow-gpu and keras utilising only 2% of the gpu during training?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, gpu, image-segmentation

I am trying to run my multi-class image segmentation problem using tensorflow-gpu as the backend to Keras on both a single gpu and multiple gpus. what i'm finding is the training is running extremely slowly. When I look at the utilisation I can see that the GPU is barely being used, around 2%. I have roughly 10,000 images and masks that are (224x224x3) each and I convert the masks to categorical friendly one-hot-encoded structure such that I have four classes and masks with shape (224x224x4). I am using a standard unet encoder, decoder architecture. Using the sequence class I have written my own custom generator that grabs both images and masks and does the preprocessing. I wondered whether my training is slow because my custom generator is some sort of bottleneck in the process? Am I doing too much preprocessing in the generator itself (i.e resizing images etc) I'm not sure how else to explain why it is taking so long to train. Below I have included three scripts 1. the unet model 2. the custom generator and 3. the segmentation script that compiles the model and trains it and calls the generators. Any help as to why this is happening would be massively appreciated.

I also believe that I'm correctly using tensorflow-gpu and the GPU avaliable becasue I get the following message

```
GPU Prolog Script v0.30
This is a GPU node.
Enough GPUs available.
Allocating card 1
2020-03-05 10:40:05.996313: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-03-05 10:40:06.078021: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:03:00.0
2020-03-05 10:40:06.127190: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-03-05 10:40:06.221801: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2020-03-05 10:40:06.296413: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2020-03-05 10:40:06.379031: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2020-03-05 10:40:06.429316: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2020-03-05 10:40:06.485672: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2020-03-05 10:40:06.791850: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-03-05 10:40:06.796626: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-03-05 10:40:06.797199: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-03-05 10:40:06.813236: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2400010000 Hz
2020-03-05 10:40:06.815750: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x535a0a0 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2020-03-05 10:40:06.815778: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-03-05 10:40:07.000335: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x53bd360 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2020-03-05 10:40:07.000385: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, Compute Capability 6.1
2020-03-05 10:40:07.002638: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:03:00.0
2020-03-05 10:40:07.002714: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-03-05 10:40:07.002747: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2020-03-05 10:40:07.002774: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2020-03-05 10:40:07.002802: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2020-03-05 10:40:07.002829: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2020-03-05 10:40:07.002856: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2020-03-05 10:40:07.002884: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-03-05 10:40:07.010122: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-03-05 10:40:07.023584: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-03-05 10:40:07.026875: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1159] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-03-05 10:40:07.026902: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1165]      0
2020-03-05 10:40:07.026919: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1178] 0:   N
2020-03-05 10:40:07.034045: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1304] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10481 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2020-03-05 10:54:36.697783: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-03-05 10:54:39.743744: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
```

1. ```
   import tensorflow as tf
   from tensorflow import keras
   import numpy as np

   class Unet():
         def __init__(self, imgDims, nOutput=1, finalActivation='sigmoid', activation='relu', padding='same'):
             self.imgDims = imgDims
             self.activation = activation
             self.finalActivation = finalActivation
             self.padding = padding
             self.nOutput = nOutput

         def convBlocks(self, x, filters, kernelSize=(3,3), padding='same', strides=1):

             x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
             x = keras.layers.Activation(self.activation)(x)
             x = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernelSize, padding=padding, strides=strides)(x)

             return x


         def identity(self, x, xInput, f, padding='same', strides=1):

             skip = keras.layers.Conv2D(f, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding=padding, strides=strides)(xInput)
             skip = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(skip)
             output = keras.layers.Add()([skip, x])

             return output


         def residualBlock(self, xIn, f, stride):

             res = self.convBlocks(xIn, f, strides=stride)
             res = self.convBlocks(res, f, strides=1)
             output = self.identity(res, xIn, f, strides=stride)

            return output


        def upSampling(self, x, xInput):

            x = keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2,2))(x)
            x = keras.layers.Concatenate()([x, xInput])

           return x


        def encoder(self, x, filters, kernelSize=(3,3), padding='same', strides=1):

           e1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters[0], kernelSize, padding=padding, strides=strides)(x)
           e1 = self.convBlocks(e1, filters[0])

           shortcut = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters[0], kernel_size=(1, 1), padding=padding, strides=strides)(x)
           shortcut = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(shortcut)
           e1Output = keras.layers.Add()([e1, shortcut])

           e2 = self.residualBlock(e1Output, filters[1], stride=2)
           e3 = self.residualBlock(e2, filters[2], stride=2)
           e4 = self.residualBlock(e3, filters[3], stride=2)
           e5 = self.residualBlock(e4, filters[4], stride=2)

           return e1Output, e2, e3, e4, e5


         def bridge(self, x, filters):

           b1 = self.convBlocks(x, filters, strides=1)
           b2 = self.convBlocks(b1, filters, strides=1)

           return b2


       def decoder(self, b2, e1, e2, e3, e4, filters, kernelSize=(3,3), padding='same', strides=1):

           x = self.upSampling(b2, e4)
           d1 = self.convBlocks(x, filters[4])
           d1 = self.convBlocks(d1, filters[4])
           d1 = self.identity(d1, x, filters[4])

           x = self.upSampling(d1, e3)
           d2 = self.convBlocks(x, filters[3])
           d2 = self.convBlocks(d2, filters[3])
           d2 = self.identity(d2, x, filters[3])

           x = self.upSampling(d2, e2)
          d3 = self.convBlocks(x, filters[2])
          d3 = self.convBlocks(d3, filters[2])
          d3 = self.identity(d3, x, filters[2])

          x = self.upSampling(d3, e1)
          d4 = self.convBlocks(x, filters[1])
          d4 = self.convBlocks(d4, filters[1])
          d4 = self.identity(d4, x, filters[1])

          return d4


      def ResUnet(self, filters = [16, 32, 64, 128, 256]):

          inputs = keras.layers.Input((self.imgDims, self.imgDims, 3))

          e1, e2, e3, e4, e5 = self.encoder(inputs, filters)
          b2 = self.bridge(e5, filters[4])
          d4 = self.decoder(b2, e1, e2, e3, e4, filters)

          x = keras.layers.Conv2D(self.nOutput, (1, 1), padding='same', activation=self.finalActivation)(d4)
          model = keras.models.Model(inputs, x)

          return model
   ```

2.

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from skimage import img_as_bool
from skimage.transform import resize


class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, imgIds, maskIds, imagePath, maskPath, weights=[1,1,1,1],
                        batchSize=16, imageSize = (224, 224, 3), nClasses=4, shuffle=False):
        self.imgIds = imgIds
        self.maskIds = maskIds
        self.imagePath = imagePath
        self.maskPath = maskPath
        self.weights = np.array(weights)
        self.batchSize = batchSize
        self.imageSize = imageSize
        self.nClasses = nClasses
        self.shuffle = shuffle





    '''
    for each image id load the patch and corresponding mask
    '''
    def __load__(self, imgName, maskName):

        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(self.imagePath,imgName))
        img = cv2.resize(img, (self.imageSize[0], self.imageSize[1]))
        img = img/255.0

        mask = cv2.imread(os.path.join(self.maskPath,maskName))
        mask = img_as_bool(resize(mask, (self.imageSize[0], self.imageSize[1])))
        mask = np.dstack((mask, np.zeros((224, 224))))
        mask = mask.astype('uint16')
        mask[:,:,3][mask[:,:,0]==0]=1
        mask = self.weightMasks(mask)

        return (img, mask)


    '''
    get the files for each batch (override __getitem__ method)
    '''
    def __getitem__(self, index):

        if(index+1)*self.batchSize > len(self.imgIds):
            self.batchSize = len(self.imgIds) - index*self.batchSize

        batchImgs = self.imgIds[self.batchSize*index:self.batchSize*(index+1)]
        batchMasks = self.maskIds[self.batchSize*index:self.batchSize*(index+1)]
        batchfiles = [self.__load__(imgFile, maskFile) for imgFile, maskFile in zip(batchImgs, batchMasks)]
        images, masks = zip(*batchfiles)

        return np.array(list(images)), np.array(list(masks))


    '''
    Return number of steps per batch that are needed (override __len__ method)
    '''
    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.imgIds)/self.batchSize))
```

3.

```
import os
import csv
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np
import pickle
import random
import argparse
import json
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
from tensorflow import keras
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage import img_as_bool
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

from scripts.resunet_multi import Unet
from scripts.fcn8 import FCN
from scripts.utilities import saveModel, saveHistory
from scripts.evaluation import dice_coef_loss, dice_coef
from scripts.custom_datagenerator_three import DataGenerator
from scripts.custom_loss_functions import weightedCatXEntropy


def getPrediction(model, validGenerator, validIds):

    steps = len(validIds)//validGenerator.batchSize

    for i in range(0, steps):
        x, y = validGenerator.__getitem__(i)
        y[y==1]=255
        masks.append(y)
        yPred = model.predict(x)
        yPred = np.argmax(yPred, axis=3)

        for img in yPred:
                x, y = validGenerator.__getitem__(i)
                y[y==1]=255
                masks.append(y)
                yPred = model.predict(x)
                yPred = np.argmax(yPred, axis=3)


def trainSegmentationModel(args):

    basePath = args['basepath']
    imageDir = args['imagedir']
    maskDir = args['maskdir']

    if args['weightfile'] is not None:
        with open(args['weightfile'], 'r') as txtFile:
            weights = list(csv.reader(txtFile, delimiter=','))

    with open(args['paramfile']) as jsonFile:
        params = json.load(jsonFile)

    print(params['nClasses'])

    if args['model'] == 'unet':
        unet =  Unet(int(params['imageDims']), nOutput = int(params['nClasses']), finalActivation=params['final'])
        model = unet.ResUnet()
    elif args['model'] == 'fcn8':
        fcn = FCN(int(params['imageDims']), nClasses = int(params['nClasses']), finalActivation=params['final'])
        model = fcn.getFCN8()

    epoch = int(params['epoch'])
    ratio = float(params['ratio'])

    imagePath = os.path.join(basePath, imageDir)
    maskPath = os.path.join(basePath, maskDir)

    imgIds = glob.glob(os.path.join(imagePath, '*'))
    imgIds = [os.path.basename(f) for f in imgIds][:200]
    maskIds = glob.glob(os.path.join(maskPath, '*'))
    maskIds = [os.path.basename(f) for f in maskIds][:200]
    trainNum = round(ratio*len(imgIds))
    validNum = np.floor((len(imgIds) - trainNum))

    trainIds = imgIds[:trainNum]
    validIds = imgIds[trainNum:]
    #testIds = imgIds[(trainNum+validNum):]
    trainMasks = maskIds[:trainNum]
    validMasks = maskIds[trainNum:]
    #testMasks = maskIds[(trainNum+validNum):]

    trainGenerator = DataGenerator(trainIds, trainMasks, imagePath, maskPath)
    validGenerator = DataGenerator(validIds, validMasks, imagePath, maskPath)
    #testGenerator = DataGenerator(testIds, validMasks, imagePath, maskPath)

    trainSteps = len(trainIds)//trainGenerator.batchSize
    validSteps = len(validIds)//validGenerator.batchSize

    if args['weightfile'] is None:
        for i in range(trainSteps):
            _, m = trainGenerator.__getitem__(i)
            mask = np.argmax(m, axis=3)
            labels.append(mask.reshape(-1))

        labels = [l.tolist() for l in labels]
        labels = itertools.chain(*labels)
        weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(labels), labels)

    #learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False
    adam = keras.optimizers.Adam()
    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=weightedCatXEntropy, metrics=[dice_coef])

    trainSteps = len(trainIds)//trainGenerator.batchSize
    validSteps = len(validIds)//validGenerator.batchSize

    history = model.fit_generator(trainGenerator,
                    validation_data=validGenerator,
                    steps_per_epoch=trainSteps,
                    validation_steps=validSteps,
                    verbose=1,
                    epochs=epoch)

    saveModel(model, args['name'])
    saveHistory(history, args['name']+'_hist')

    #getPrediction(model, validGenerator, validIds)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument('-bp', '--basepath', required=True, help='path to image and mask directories')
    ap.add_argument('-ip', '--imagedir', required=True, help='path to image directory')
    ap.add_argument('-mp', '--maskdir', required=True, help='path to image directory')
    ap.add_argument('-m', '--model', required=True, help='neural network model to use')
    ap.add_argument('-n', '--name', required=True, help='name to save the model with')
    ap.add_argument('-wf', '--weightfile', help='file containing list of class weights for unbalanced datasets')
    ap.add_argument('-pf', '--paramfile', help='file containing parameters')

    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

    trainSegmentationModel(args)
```

Comment: You're probably not using the GPU, is your tensorflow correctly configured for GPU? You must follow strict instructions and install the exact cuda version, the exact tensorflow version, etc. Look in the tensorflow website for the instructions.

Comment: the output (see edit above) suggests that tensorflow-gpu is correctly configured and I am using the GPU

Answer (score 2):

You could try running a profiling to your training. There's a nice tutorial here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras
Note that in some cases, it is not very easy to follow and understand it, but it may be very useful as well.

One more tip: Given that you process the images and masks with several operations, I would seriously consider to preprocess the whole training and validation sets, so that in your generator you only have to read them from files and nothing more. This way, it is highly probable that you save critical time at training (and validation) time *for every epoch*.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I will check out the profiling - I agree the processing i'm currently doing in the generator may cause some of the problem

Comment: @maracuja have you profiled the training? Have you found the answer to you question?